# A representation induced from one subgroup and restricted to another

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Denote with $\,{\cal{L}}^G\,$ the space of all continuous functions $\varphi(g)$ mapping the elements of a Lie group $G$ to some vector space ${\cal{L}}$:
 $$
 {\cal{L}}^{G}~=~\left\{~\varphi~~~{\Large{|}}~~~\varphi\,:~G\,\longrightarrow\,{\cal{L}}\right\}~~.
 $$
 Consider a subgroup $K<G$ and its representation $D(K)$ by linear operators on ${\cal{L}}^{G}\,$:
 $$
 D:\quad K~\longrightarrow~{\rm{GL}}({\cal{L}}^{G})~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
 $$
 It can be induced to the representation $\,\mbox{Ind}_K^GD\,$ on the subspace of functions obeying
 $$
 \varphi(xk^{-1})=D(k)\varphi(x)~.~~~\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
 $$
 We now restrict the induced representation to a subgroup $\,B<G\,$. Denoted with
 $$
 U(B)~\equiv~\left(D(K)~\uparrow~G\right)~\downarrow~B~~,\quad\quad\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (3)
 $$
 the new representation will be realised with the left translations
 $$
 U(b)~\varphi(g)~=~\varphi(b^{-1}g)~~.~\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (4)
 $$

This representation fixes the double cosets $\,Bu_iK\,$. So the expansion
 $$
 G\,=\,\,\bigcup_i{\cal{U}}_{\,i}\,=\,\,\bigcup_iB\, u_i\, K\,\;\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad~ (5)
 $$
 yields a decomposition of $\,U(B)\,$ into subrepresentations:
 $$
 U(b^{\,\prime})\,\varphi(b\, u\, k)~=~\varphi({b^{\,\prime}}^{-\, 1}\, b\,u\, k)~~,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (6)
 $$
 where $~~b\, u\, k~$ and $~{b^{\,\prime}}^{-\, 1} b\, u\, k~$ belong to the same  $~B\, u\, K\,$.

Define the projection operator $\,P_u\,$ so that a function $\,P_u\varphi\,$ coincides with $\,\varphi\,$ on $\,B\, u\, K\,$ and is zero outside it.
 Then interpret $\,\varphi(g)\,$  as a set of functions $\,\varphi_u\,$ on double cosets:
 $$
 \varphi~=~\left\{\,\varphi_u\,\right\}~~,\qquad\varphi_u\,=~P_u\,\varphi~~.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad (8)
 $$

A function $\,\varphi_u\,$ is fully defined by its values on $\,B\, u\,$, owing to (2) which now becomes
 $$
 \varphi_u(b\, u\, k)=D(k^{-1})\varphi_u(b\, u)~\,.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad~~~ (9)
 $$
 Defining
 $$
 q\,\equiv\, u\, k\, u^{-1}\,\in\, K_u\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (10)
 $$
 and introducing a representation of $\,K_u\,$
 $$
 D_u(q)\,\equiv\, D(u^{-1}\, q\, u)~~,~~\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (11)
 $$
 we can also write the subsidiary condition on $\,\varphi\,$ as a subsidiary condition
 $$
 \Phi_u(b\, q)~=~D^{-1}_u(q)~\Phi_u(b)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (12)
 $$
 on a new function
 $$
 \Phi_u(b\, q)~\equiv\,\varphi_u(b\, q\, u)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (13)
 $$
 acting as
 $$
 \Phi_u\,:~~~B\,K_u~\longrightarrow~{\cal{L}}~~.~~\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (14)
 $$
 Thus, our subrepresentation becomes
 $\;
 D_u(K_u)\uparrow B
 \;$, while the entire representation is
 $$
 \left(D(K)~\uparrow~G\right)~\downarrow~B~=~\int_{B\backslash G/K}du ~D_u(K_u)\uparrow B
 ~,\qquad\qquad\qquad (15)
 $$
 where the integration goes over all distinct double cosets.

Strangely, this is not what I see in the books. E.g., the Mathematical Encyclopedia says that

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Induced_representation
 $$
 \left(D(K)~\uparrow~G\right)~\downarrow~B~=~\int_{B\backslash G/K}du ~(D_u(K_u)\downarrow L_u)\uparrow B
 ~,\qquad~~~ (16)
 $$
where
 $$
L_u~\equiv~K_u\cap B~=~u~K~u^{-1}\cap B~~.
 $$

My question is: why $\,~\downarrow L_u\,$?

This restriction is equivalent to an assumption that in condition (12) we must restrict, by hand,
 $\,q\,$ from $\,K_u\,$ to $\,L_u\,$. Or to enforce an equivalent restriction of $\,k\,$ in $\,D(K)\,$. Or to restrict the domain of $\,\Phi\,$ to $\,B\,$ in (12). Why should we do that? The desired restriction of the induced representation to $\,B\,$ implies that the left translations must be performed by the elements $\,b\in B\,$. I, however, see no reason why we also should restrict to $\,B\,$ the domain of the functions $\,\Phi\,$ on which this restricted representation acts.

PS.

A possible clue to this problem may lie in the following observation. The subgroup $\,L_u\,$ and the quotient space $\,B/L_u\,$ naturally emerge when we split a double coset $\,BuK\,$ into left cosets $\,\textsf{b}uK\,$.

Indeed, if some $\,b\,$ and $\,b_1\,$ lie in the same left coset,
$$
b~u~K~=~b_1~u~K~~,
$$
then
$$
b~K_u~=~b_1~K_u~~~
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
b_1^{-1}b~K_u~=~K_u~~.
$$
This obviously entails $\,b_1^{-1}b\,\in\,K_u\,$, wherefrom
$$
b^{-1}_1b\,\in\,L_u~~.
$$
So the left cosets $\,b\, u\, K\,$ and $\,b_1 u\, K\,$ coincide iff $\,b\,$ and $\,b_1\,$ belong to the same left coset in the quotient space $\,B/L_u\;$,$\,$ with some  representative  $\,\textsf{b}\,$:
$$
 b\,,\,b_1\,\in\,\textsf{b}\,{{L}}_{u}\;\,,\;\;\,\textsf{b}\,\in\,B
$$
 Thus, as many left cosets $\,\textsf{b}\, L_u\,$ in the quotient space $\,B/L_u\,$ so many left cosets $\,X\,=\, \textsf{b}\, u\, K\,$ in the double coset $\,{\cal{U}}=BuK\,$.

We also can say that if $\,b\,$ lies in the left coset $\,b\, u\, K\,$, then
$$
b~=~\textsf{b}~l~~,~~~l\in L_u~~,
$$
where $\,\textsf{b}\,$ is a representative of the left coset $\,\textsf{b}\,L_u\,$.
Thence, 
$$
\Phi_u(b)~=~D_u^{-1}(l)~\Phi_u(\textsf{b})~~,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\qquad\qquad(17)
$$
so the function $\,\Phi_u\,$ is fully defined by its values on a section of the quotient space $\,B/L_u\,$.

This could have answered my question if not for one circumstance: in eqn (12) we still have $\,q\,$ which lies in $\,K_u\,$, not in $\,L_u\,$. So equation (17) becomes
$$
\Phi(bq)~=~D_u^{-1}(lq)~\Phi_u(\textsf{b})~~,
$$
and the subrepresentation is defined not on $\,L_u\,$ but on $\,K_u\,$ -- unless we fix this ``by hand'' (but on what grounds?)

Comment: There was too much text here for me to read in detail, but we need to restrict because we can't do induction from something which is not a subgroup of the thing we induct to.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I agree. If we introduce an a priori demand that the representation must be built by induction to B -- then yes, we have first to restrict everything to a subgroup $\,L_u < B\,$. However, isn't this demand by itself excessive? We have a representation of $\,B\,$ on a broader class of functions, eqn (12), with $q\in K_u~,$ not $q\in L_u$. What is the fundamental motivation to restrict the domain of $\,q\,$ there? Solely for the purpose of the eventual representation being induced?